Can somebody explain to me one of the Bell experiments?
I can't understand the experiment in this paper.
In this experiment, two electrons at different points $A$ and $B$ are entangled with one photon each. Then, the photons are entangled in point $C$ which is between $A$ and $B$. So electrons become part of the one quantum system. Then, the spins of the electrons are measured. The authors claim that they able to detect when the electrons are entangled and when they are not based on Bell's inequality.
For me, that seems like if the point $C$ will be moved to other side of the galaxy, then the fact that electrons are entangled will be detected with superluminal speed. Where am I wrong?
After some comments I add explanation to describe what actually confused me:
In point $A$ you have two electrons (not entangled) and two photons entangled with one of the electrons each. You send these photons to point $B$ on other side of the galaxy. In point $B$ you can entangle photons (after that electrons in point $A$ also become entangled instantly) or not. In point $A$ you check whether electrons are entangled or not (that possible by Bell's theorem). This is signal.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is actually an excellent question, and the answer itself is very important to understand when considering spacetime extended entangled quantum systems.
First, the cited experiment is important because it is specifically designed to simultaneously close a group of so-called possible "loopholes" in Bell experiments that rule out local realistic theories.  Not that many people believed these loopholes were viable, but good science demands they be explored.  The Hensen et al experiment uses entanglement swapping as its method of entangling particles at points A and B.  The swap occurs at point C.  Explaining the details is best left to the references and cannot be properly covered in this answer.
However, the basic entanglement swap consists of taking 2 independent particle pairs (each pair being an entangled electron and photon, one pair at at point A and the other at point B) and then sending the photon of each pair to point C.  (Note that the referenced experiments label these differently, so I am using the OP cited experiment's labeling.)  Then, at C the photons arriving from A and B are allowed to interact and are then measured as to polarization (spin).  When these 2 photons arrive so close in time together that they become indistinguishable, this is called a Bell State Measurement (BSM).  The successful BSM casts these into 1 of 4 Bell states (these are all entangled states).  It also casts the electrons remaining at points A and B into a matching Bell state, so now those particles are entangled with each other as well.  This entanglement between the particles remaining at A and B occurs completely remotely!  Distance is not a factor.  Note that the selection of which of the 4 Bell states occurs is outside the control of the experimenter, and occurs randomly.
Further, and counter-intuitively: Ordering of execution of the swap is not a factor.  In this experiment, the BSM (swap) at C can occur not only anywhere - it can occur any time!  The newly entangled particles at A and B can even be measured - revealing a violation of a Bell inequality such as CHSH - BEFORE the BSM occurs at point C.  (This point has been experimentally verified previously by multiple teams.)
So the OP is asking essentially: if you place C on the other side of the galaxy, you could see entanglement at A & B that has not yet occurred by the swap at C.  And by suitable selection and timing, you might even be able to get superluminal signaling, right?
Of course there is a hitch that prevents that, just as we must expect.  The BSM - entanglement swap - casts the remaining A and B particles into 1 of 4 Bell States.    In 2 of those states, the A/B pair is perfectly correlated.  In the other 2, the A/B pair is perfectly anti-correlated.  So to decipher the entanglement present at A and B, you need to know which of the 4 Bell states is created at C.  Are they correlated, or anti-correlated?  Learning that requires all of those results to be communicated by a classical signal, limited to c.  Further, ordering is important for this because this knowledge cannot be determined until all the results are brought together at one spot.  And voila, we are right back to an apparently normal causal sequence.
So to conclude: The entanglement itself can be created remotely (distant/nonlocal/FTL) and defy normal causal ordering; although the knowledge of this cannot.  So no signaling possible, even though the effect itself is demonstrated.
References:
Experimental loophole-free violation of a Bell inequality using entangled electron spins separated by 1.3 km
Hensen et al (2015)
From abstract of paper cited by OP: For more than 80 years, the counterintuitive predictions of quantum theory have stimulated debate about the nature of reality. In his seminal work, John Bell proved that no theory of nature that obeys locality and realism can reproduce all the predictions of quantum theory. Bell showed that in any local realist theory the correlations between distant measurements satisfy an inequality and, moreover, that this inequality can be violated according to quantum theory. This provided a recipe for experimental tests of the fundamental principles underlying the laws of nature. In the past decades, numerous ingenious Bell inequality tests have been reported. However, because of experimental limitations, all experiments to date required additional assumptions to obtain a contradiction with local realism, resulting in loopholes. Here we report on a Bell experiment that is free of any such additional assumption and thus directly tests the principles underlying Bell’s inequality...
High-fidelity entanglement swapping with fully independent sources
Kaltenbaek et al (2008)
This is a somewhat similar earlier paper more focused on entanglement swapping itself rather than the loophole issue.
"The resulting correlations between particles that do not share any common past [independent suitably distant sources] are strong enough to violate a Clauser-Horne-Shimony-Holt (CHSH) inequality. ... We confirm successful entanglement swapping by testing the entanglement of the previously uncorrelated photons 1 and 4." In other words, the swapping operation entangles the 1 & 4 photons in this experiment, which are analogous to the A & B particles of the Hensen experiment.
Note: Both of these experiments have an S value of about 2.4, well above the local realistic threshold of 2.0 but lower than the ideal quantum mechanical prediction of about 2.8.  There is no problem with these results, it is absolutely to be expected.  Any experimental issues will lower the S value; and in fact there is a built in issue due to the necessity of establishing a coincidence time window.  A narrow window provides more fidelity with a corresponding decrease in successful swap events.  A wider window tends to increase distinguishability which reduces successful swaps as a percentage of all events, lowering S.  So there is a balance to be struck.
To understand why the electrons at points A & B cannot be somehow entangled with each other to begin with: A maximally entangled particle cannot be entangled with more than 1 other particle.  This is called Monogamy of Entanglement. Since the A electron is initially maximally entangled with a photon, it cannot be also entangled to the B electron (and vice versa).

You write: "It also casts the particles remaining at points A and B into a matching Bell state, so now those particles are entangled with each other as well. This entanglement between the particles remaining at A and B occurs completely remotely!"  Okay, but would you have the same perspective if "C" is moved far into the future, beyond the future lightcones of A and B?  (So-called Delayed Choice Entanglement Swapping.). If you wouldn't use the same language to explain what is going on in that case, then what is the difference here?  It's the same observable effect in both cases.

@KenWharton Of course I would describe it the same, and I believe most would as well using the orthodox view.  Delayed or not, the theory and the effect is the same - exactly as you say. Obviously, this is also a function of any assumptions about causality you do or don't make.

Interesting -- creating true entanglement in the past retrocausally!  That's definitely a minority view (not even mine); I think most physicists would say no, this was just an example of post-selecting different A-B groups at C, and that there was never any "real" entanglement between A and B.  Such A-B entanglement never shows up in the math of a conventional forward-time QM calculation of this situation, anyway.

@KenWharton The words from a Zeilinger paper: "Whether these two particles are
entangled or separable [not entangled] has been decided after they have been measured. If one views the quantum state as a real physical object, one could get the seemingly paradoxical situation that future actions appear as having an influence on past and already irrevocably recorded events. However, there is never a paradox if the quantum state is viewed as to be no more than a “catalogue of our knowledge". You can read this as you like, it's consistent with my words. The entanglement IS real, however it works.

@DrChinese thank you. If we turn time backwards, then this experiment starts with a photon parametric down-conversion at C, which travel until both photons hit the identically prepared electrons at A and B, which thus transfer the entanglement, right? Then the time-reverse process should be 2 random electrons A and B emitting a photon each (by Bremsstrahlung) which travel to C. If the photons cannot be distinguished at C, then the electrons' spins at the Bremsstrahlung creation stage must be correlated in some way, which explains why sifting only these cases gives rise to spin correlations?

@James Not sure I follow your time-reversed version of the Hensen experiment. Hensen is a very specialized version of swapping specific to its particular goal: eliminating loopholes. Most entanglement swapping experiments are similar to the Kaltenbaek setup. That can be varied to have just about any relative locale/ordering you like. You can choose to execute the swap or not, and the final statistics change from Entangled State to Product State. So that choice can be made remotely or even after measurement of the final entangled pair. And you can interpret the results in different ways.
